# Buffer error when saving waveform data from oscilloscope using pyvisa

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib, plot, raspberry-pi4, pyvisa

I am trying to communicate with my Rigol DS1104Z oscilloscope using PyVisa on RPi4. I have been able to capture basic measurements but no waveform data yet. I've found about 5 examples but none of them work anymore because PyVisa removes functions without giving equivalent replacements.

This is the most recent plotting example I could find...

```
import os
import pyvisa as visa
import numpy as np

import time

from matplotlib.ticker import LinearLocator, FormatStrFormatter
from matplotlib import cm
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

#Get the USB device, e.g. 'USB0::0x1AB1::0x0588::DS1ED141904883'
resources = visa.ResourceManager()
usbDevices = list(filter(lambda x: 'USB' in x, resources.list_resources()))
if len(usbDevices) == 0:
    print("no usb devices found")
    sys.exit(-1)
print(usbDevices[0])
myScope = resources.open_resource(usbDevices[0])
print(myScope.query('*IDN?')) #Return the Rigol’s ID string to tell us it’s there

# Initialize our scope
test = myScope

test.write(":RUN")
time.sleep(1)

test.write(":STOP")
 
# Grab the data from channel 1
test.write(":WAV:POIN:MODE RAW")

# Get the voltage scale
voltscale1 = float(test.query(":CHAN1:SCAL?"))
voltscale2 = float(test.query(":CHAN2:SCAL?"))
 
# And the voltage offset
voltoffset1 = float(test.query(":CHAN1:OFFS?"))
voltoffset2 = float(test.query(":CHAN2:OFFS?"))
 
# Get the timescale
timescale1 = float(test.query(":TIM:SCAL?"))
timescale2 = float(test.query(":TIM:SCAL?"))
 
# Get the timescale offset
timeoffset1 = float(test.query(":TIM:OFFS?"))
timeoffset2 = float(test.query(":TIM:OFFS?"))

finalDataChan1 = []

data1 = np.array(myScope.query_binary_values(":WAV:DATA? CHAN1",datatype='B')[10:])
```

Where (the rest of the program is omitted because) I've isolated the problem to the final line.

I get the following error:

```
USB0::6833::1230::DS1ZD223400795::0::INSTR
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/pyvisa_py/protocols/usbtmc.py:116: UserWarning: Unexpected MsgID format. Consider updating the device's firmware. See https://github.com/pyvisa/pyvisa-py/issues/20
  "Unexpected MsgID format. Consider updating the device's firmware. See https://github.com/pyvisa/pyvisa-py/issues/20"
RIGOL TECHNOLOGIES,DS1104Z Plus,DS1ZD223400795,00.04.04.SP4

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/pi/Documents/projects/cu/pnaci/rigol/testu2.py", line 57, in <module>
    data1 = np.array(myScope.query_binary_values(":WAV:DATA? CHAN1",datatype='B')[10:])
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/pyvisa/resources/messagebased.py", line 754, in query_binary_values
    chunk_size,
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/pyvisa/resources/messagebased.py", line 602, in read_binary_values
    self.read_bytes(expected_length - len(block), chunk_size=chunk_size)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/pyvisa/resources/messagebased.py", line 371, in read_bytes
    chunk, status = self.visalib.read(self.session, size)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/pyvisa_py/highlevel.py", line 512, in read
    data, status_code = self.sessions[session].read(count)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/pyvisa_py/usb.py", line 156, in read
    USBTimeoutException,
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/pyvisa_py/sessions.py", line 793, in _read
    current = reader()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/pyvisa_py/usb.py", line 133, in _usb_reader
    return self.interface.read(count)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/pyvisa_py/protocols/usbtmc.py", line 465, in read
    response = BulkInMessage.from_bytes(resp)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/pyvisa_py/protocols/usbtmc.py", line 113, in from_bytes
    msgid, btag, btaginverse = struct.unpack_from("BBBx", data)
struct.error: unpack_from requires a buffer of at least 4 bytes
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to save 1 million point trace from oscilloscope using PyVISA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66432540/how-to-save-1-million-point-trace-from-oscilloscope-using-pyvisa)

Comment: @Zircatron No I'm still not able to get this particular code to work. I've learned a lot and have identified the issue. I think it has to do with the query_binary_values method limiting the number of data points to 400ish. If I increase :WAV:POIN above 500 then I get the same 4 bytes error message as above. I started a bug report on github: https://github.com/pyvisa/pyvisa-py/issues/298

Comment: I don't have a scope at this time so can't test it out. I recommend using a PC (just to make sure the commands work) download a connection tool from keysight (IO libraries) or National Instruments (NI Max) and use the commands in there. This should help determin if the commands are the issue or if pyvisa is the issue. If you need any help please let me know.